# Selecionar alguns dados de tabelas diferentes

Tags: sql, select, join, inner

Renascendo o programador por aqui, estou com dificuldade com `SQL` e peço ajuda.

Tenho duas tabelas chamadas `orcamentos` e `clientes`.

Preciso selecionar todos os campos da tabela `orcamentos` e apenas o campo `nome` da tabela `clientes` quando a condição `orcamentos.id_cliente = clientes.id`.

Usei até o momento da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT * FROM orcamentos tab1
INNER JOIN clientes tab2 ON (tab1.id_cliente = tab2.id)
```

Funciona, mas retorna todos os campos da tabela cliente...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta apenas especificar os campos que deseja:

```
SELECT tab1.*, tab2.nome FROM orcamentos tab1
INNER JOIN clientes tab2 ON (tab1.id_cliente = tab2.id)
```

[Exemplos de SELECT (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187731.aspx)